# Is there any budget accommodation in Rio Branco, Acre, Brazil?

Tags: accommodation, brazil, hostels

[Lonely Planet](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/brazil/rio-branco/hotels/a/lod/363168?endDate=2017-02-25&numNights=1&startDate=2017-02-24&subtypes=Hostel) lists two hotels, starting at around €30/night. HotelsCombined starts with hotels at around €90/night. Hostels don't appear to exist.

Are there any budget ho(s)tels in Rio Branco, Acre, Brazil?

By 'budget' I mean beds for €10/night, or less. (Though, obviously, I'm now interested in anything under €30/night.)

Comment: And if you are German, expect a free bed, in a hospital :D :D

Comment: @Flimzy: Any accommodation is fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm staying at Hotel do Papai, run by two older Lebanese (I think) men (and their fairly pretty daughters). A self contained single is 80R$ (about 27 euros), including breakfast and good wifi. It's in the center and seems to be on the low end, price wise, compared to hotels in the direct vicinity.

Driving into town, I passed a bunch of fairly shabby looking hotels in what is called Vila Cidade Nova, around Rua Pocos de Caldas. As the crow flies, this is close to downtown Rio Branco. However, with no direct access across the river, it would be a 2k, or so, walk to the central square.

I didn't confirm the price for rooms at these hotels, but considering their location and state, I think it safe to assume they would fall in the 'budget' category.

Answer (score 1):

I tried Lonely Plant for Hostels (link in OP) and it offered Amazônia Hostel for $16 for the night I chose (Feb 24, 2017).